# Setting tabindex

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tabindex

In wpf Textbox has TabIndex property to set the tab order, this is working fine when the controls are in the same context, In my case i have a listbox whose itemstyle has a text box and the style is assigned dynamically based on trigger. now how can i do the tabindexing so that when i tab index moves from textbox in first listboxitem to the textbox or combobox or button in the next listboxitem and as to the further listboxitems.

Thanks

Arvind

Comment: Specify which language you are using?

Comment: I am using .net 3.5  wpf with C#

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `TabNavigation` attached property so that WPF knows what to do when the user presses tab and there are no more controls in the current scope to tab to:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Continue"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Above I specify that when there are no more items in the `ListBoxItem` on which to focus, pressing tab should continue to the next logical focus container (ie. the next `ListBoxItem`).

Comment: This still does not tab to the next listboxitem textbox. focus is lost once tabed out from first textbox.

Comment: KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation should be set on the listbox. In addition you need IsTabStop = false for the listboxitem.
Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597628/wpf-databinding-a-listbox-where-each-item-is-a-tab-stop