# Inheriting default style of ItemContainerStyle in WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

To allow correct tab order through controls rendered via a ListView, I've added this to the top of my ListView control:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Which works fine for the tabs, but it also breaks the mouseover style of the listview in question.

I tried to get it back by inheriting the default:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ItemContainerStyle}}">
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Which causes the build to break with the message "cannot set properties on property elements".

So I tried changing the mousover style of the item to match what's in the stylesheet:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#90C8E0" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And that won't compile, complaining that IsMouseOver and Background are not recognised properties for ItemContainter.

So I tried creating a style for it in my stylesheet, and giving it a key:

```
<Style x:Key="TabbedListItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
</Style>

<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TabbedListItem}" />
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Which compiles, but won't render, throwing the error " 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception".

I'm out of ideas. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you copy the whole `ListView`? I tried your first `Style`, it worked for me. Didn't break the hover style.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi Thanks for looking and trying it out. I can copy it all if it's helpful, but that would be a lot of code, especially including external style xaml. We're using the metro theme by default, which may explain why mine behaves differently?